# CEP --- is there a big difference between Oracle EPL and what is offered by ESPER?

Tags: oracle, complex-event-processing, esper, epl

I'm new to CEP and looking into playing with ESPER. I was doing some general googling on the topic and came a cross this:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13157_01/wlevs/docs30/pdf/epl_guide.pdf

And also this:

http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.2.0/doc/reference/en/html/

Can someone clarify what is the difference? I started reading the Oracle one because it had pictures... :) But I don't have Oracle $, so likely will be using ESPER.

So are there significant differences or are they more or less the same thing, as far as "EPL" goes, with minor differences like Oracle vs MS "sql"... (Don't get attached to this last statement, just using it as a euphemism of sorts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Esper current release is 7.0.0.
The doc: http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.0.0/esper-reference/html/index.html

Rest everything is at http://www.espertech.com

Comment: I see. Oracle is listed on the partners page of ESPER. Does that mean their EPL is identical?